# Conditional on Function Evaluation Preempts Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a question similar to this: [How do I wait for a promise to finish before returning the variable of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759593/how-do-i-wait-for-a-promise-to-finish-before-returning-the-variable-of-a-functio)

I have a function `pass()` that does some form validation. As part of this, it will sometimes open a modal that the user has to close before it returns a value, like so:

```
if ($scope.model.validation == "No") {
  $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    templateUrl: 'pleaseval.html',
    controller: 'PleaseValCtrl',
    size: 'lg'
  }).closed.then(function() {
    return true;
  });
}
```

Note that it doesn't `return true` until the modal closes.

However, I have a conditional based on the function's evaluation

```
if(pass(form))
{
//some code here
}
else{
alert("Please fill out all the required information before hitting 'Next'");
}
```

Because it waits for a promise (the modal to close) it returns `false` and fires the alert, without waiting for the modal to close and actually firing `true`.

How do I structure this code so as to not fire the alert while waiting for the modal to close?

Thank you!

**Edit:** I should note that I can do this:

```
pass(form).then(function(result){
if(result)
{
```

The problem with this is that if arguments are passed to `pass()` that don't necessitate waiting for the modal, I get an undefined promise.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: Can you explain why you're using a promise here? Is `pass` a long running validation backend process?

If you're merely running client-side validation, sticking to a synchronous call will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your edit, it sounds like `pass` sometimes returns a promise.  FYI, in the future, the full code of `pass` would be helpful, particularly around what it returns - your posted code actually shows nothing about what `pass` returns, since the "return true" isn't actually what `pass` itself is returning.

You need to ensure pass always returns a promise in every code path.  If the modal isn't necessary, and you have a synchronous return value, make `pass` return `Promise.resolve(true);` - that is, the value of true, but wrapped as a promise so the return value of `pass` is always thenable.  That way, the caller of `pass` doesn't need to know or care whether the operation completed sychronously or asynchronously.

Comment: `Promise.resolve(true);` does not fire true for the `if(result)` part... do I have to pass additional parameters?

Comment: @SummerDeveloper Post the full code of `pass` - or at least every part that handles flow control (promises, if/else, return, etc).

Comment: Well it actually works, it just broke something else down the line which is confusing but outside of the scope of this question I believe.