# Javascript wait for Promise to complete inside for-loop before returning response

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise, return

I am trying to respond after a Promise within a for-loop is complete.

I have looked at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?noredirect=1&lq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759593/how-do-i-wait-for-a-promise-to-finish-before-returning-the-variable-of-a-functio), but they don't address my situation.

The methodGetOrders and methodGetLines are part of an external library that I have to use. They both make network calls, so there is some expected lag. The function always returns a '0', since it doesn't wait for the inner promise to complete. I realize there is no way to 'wait' for the promise to complete, but how do I get the correct value of counter in the response?

```
doWorkMainFunction() {
  methodGetOrders()
    .then(orderList =>  {
       var counter=0;
       for (var i=0; i< orderList.length; i++) {
         methodGetLines()
           .then (lineData => {
              if (someCondition) { counter++; }
            } // end of inner THEN
       } // end FOR loop
       return counter; // This always returns '0'
   } // end of outer THEN
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of all the promises in the loop and then use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to return counter after all those promises have resolved

```
methodGetOrders()
  .then(orderList => {
    var counter = 0;

    var promises = orderList.map(order => {
      return methodGetLines()
        .then(lineData => {
          if (someCondition) {
            counter++;
          }
        }) // end of inner THEN
    }) // end promise map
    return Promise.all(promises).then(_ => counter);
  }) // end of outer THEN
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I am fairly new to JavaScript, so I want to be clear about something: there are two return statements in the code? Is that 'allowed'?

Comment: You can have as many return statements as you want to. The ones here are even in different functions.

Comment: The first `return` is inside [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to give it each array item which happens to be a promise returned by `methodGetLines()`  ...second returns to `methodGetOrders`.