# Promise rejected and unable to getCollections or getItems within VUE and Directus

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, directus, headless-cms

Newbie to the world of vueJS and Directus. Learning my way through things by going through the online documentation. Still looking for a decent tutorial showing step by step instructions on how to access a remote install of Directus and use its data in a vueJS app.

My setup is as follows:

- vueJS app being developed on my local machine within VS Code Directus
  setup and running on a remote server

Within my home.js component I seem to be able to access Directus with the following and no errors in my browser console:

```
import DirectusSDK from "@directus/sdk-js";
const client = new DirectusSDK();
client.login({
  url: "https://mydomain.studio/directus/public/",
  project: "events",
  email: "email@emailaddress.com.au",
  password: "mypassword",
  storage: window.localStorage
});
```

When I attempt to output a listing of the collections with the below I get a rejected Promise and 401 unauthorized.

```
console.log(client.getCollections());
```

Hoping that once I get an understanding of why the above does not work and find a solution I will be able to access the data in my Directus seup and use it within my HTML.

All help greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

If there is a newbie step-by-step tutorial explaining how to do the above I would be very glad to go over it.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Are you waiting for the login to complete first?  Or is `client.getCollections` as you've shown it on the very next line?

Comment: `client.getCollections` is on the next line. I have no idea how to test to ensure that the Promise has been resolved

Comment: Can you post the full component script (no template needed)?   That way I can post something for you to try, using the format you're using.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759593/how-do-i-wait-for-a-promise-to-finish-before-returning-the-variable-of-a-functio

Comment: Thank you for taking a look this @Dan. This is part of a tutorial that I have been following [link](https://auth0.com/blog/beginner-vuejs-tutorial-with-user-login/)

The script section is below and split up due to Stack overflow not letting me post so many characters into a single comment

Comment: `<script>
import EventsList from '../components/EventsList';
export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: {
    EventsList
  },
  methods: {
    // Log the user in
    login() {
      this.$auth.loginWithRedirect();
    }
  }
}

`

Comment: `// DirectusSDK - https://docs.directus.io/getting-started/introduction.html
import DirectusSDK from "@directus/sdk-js";

const client = new DirectusSDK();

// This returns a promise - don't try to access any data until this promise resolves
client.login({
  url: "https://mydomain.studio/directus/public/",
  project: "events",
  email: "email@mail.com",
  password: "[AZX%h9opTC",
  storage: window.localStorage
});

console.log(client.getCollections());
</script>`

Comment: It would be even better if you can edit that info into your post instead, but no worries, I'll just post an answer for now and you can try it.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer:  I have no idea what Directus is.  But something like this should technically work according to their docs:

```js
import DirectusSDK from "@directus/sdk-js";

const client = new DirectusSDK({
  url: "https://mydomain.studio/directus/public/",
  project: "events",
  storage: window.localStorage
});

client.login({
  email: "email@emailaddress.com.au",
  password: "mypassword",
}).then(response => {
  console.log(client.getCollections());
});
```