# JS init function not waiting for another function to completed

Tags: javascript

In my JS I want to wait for this `fnDocumentTypeCount` to be compelted before I go into the other with the logic for the init but it will not wait for that function to be completed.fnDocumentTypeCount is a `$.ajax` that I was going to return a number.

```
    init: function () {
    var countType = fnDocumentTypeCount(GroupId);
    console.log(countType);
    }
```

Comment: use a promise management!

Comment: Is it async? There's not enough context here to know what specifically you're asking. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and possibly [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992).

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759593/how-do-i-wait-for-a-promise-to-finish-before-returning-the-variable-of-a-functio#27759617

Comment: although the code you showed looks fine, the answer lies in the code you didn't show.  You may have been using an async or promise based function that you must await.  look into promises.

Comment: I included that fnDocumentTypeCount  is returning

Answer (score -1):

Use `await`:

```js
init: async function () {
  var countType = await fnDocumentTypeCount(GroupId);
  console.log(countType);
}
```

Or here's the old way of doing this:

```js
init: function () {
  fnDocumentTypeCount(GroupId).then(countType => {
    console.log(countType);
  });
}
```

Comment: What makes you think fnDocumentTypeCount returns a promise?