# Break/return in a for loop of async calls?

Tags: javascript

Currently my function looks like this:

```
const checkDynamoID = (dynamoClient, tableName) => {
  function runCheck(client, params, id) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      client.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error",  err);
        } else {
          if (data.Item === undefined) {
            console.log("Key available: " + id)
            resolve(id)
          } else {
            console.log("Key taken: " + id)
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const randomID = this.generateRandomBase64URL()
    const dynamoParams = {
      TableName: tableName, //TABLE_NAME
      Key: {
        'videoID': { S: randomID },
      }
    }

    const res = runCheck(dynamoClient, dynamoParams, randomID).then((result) => {
      console.log("Result: " + result)
      if (typeof result !== 'undefined') {
        console.log("Result: " + result)
        return result
      }
    })
  }

  return ""
}
```

My goal is to run `runCheck`, which makes async calls to a DynamoDB to check for an ID, in a for loop until it returns a valid ID. After that, I'd like to return or break out of the external for loop that encloses the call and return from `checkDynamoID`. However, I'm not sure how to do this; I tried running this and it does not return, even after generating a valid value (ie. `typeof result !== 'undefined'`).

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Use `async`/`await`. Your current code does `return` only from the `then` callback

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? I use `then` because I want the for loop to wait until the return value from the Promise is resolved and processed.

Comment: …and that's what it *doesn't* do when you use `then`. It would work if you used `await` instead.

Comment: Was trying to follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759593/how-do-i-wait-for-a-promise-to-finish-before-returning-the-variable-of-a-functio

Do you mind sharing an example? My understanding was that `await` will return a Promise, which can resolve asynchronously. So it won't stall the for loop until the Promise is resolved.

Comment: `await` (and `async`) makes the `checkDynamoID` immediately return a promise, while stalling the `for` loop until the `await`ed promise (`runCheck(…)`) is settled. Then when the loop has finished and the function `return`s, the promise is resolved with the result.

Comment: Right, but then wouldn't I have to make `checkDynamoID` async as well? Then the code that calls `checkDynamoID` would get a Promise rather than a bool, which I don't want either. Ideally `checkDynamoID` should return a value at the end of the execution without promises.

Comment: Yes, `checkDynamoID` must return a promise, there's no way around that (regardless whether using `async`/`await` or not): it does asynchronous stuff, so it's result must be asynchronous. You cannot synchronously block, waiting for a promise to resolve. You cannot return a boolean, the value is not immediately known.